# How can I get the joint.ui.stencil.js plugin??

Tags: jointjs

I was unable to find the joint.ui.stecil.js plugin.

Can anyone suggest me on how to get the above plugin?

Thanks,
Zia

Answer (score 2):

The joint.ui.Stencil plugin is part of the commercial Rappid diagramming toolkit. See http://jointjs.com/about-rappid.